# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::search() using laravel scout and tntsearch

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-scout

in my larave-vue app I want to be able to filter by a search term using laravel scout tntsearch, along with this I also perform additional filtering, sorting or where clauses in my controller. I can't get both to work correctly in my app.

In my controller I have this:

```
$posts = Post::filter($filters)->search($request->input('query'))->paginate(0);
            $posts->load(['postcategory.section','author']);

            if($posts->isEmpty())
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'No results found',
                ],500);    
            }

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Results found',
                'posts' => $posts,
            ]);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::search()
```

For some reason It's not working, I have tried changing the order of the filter, search and paginate but I still get errors.

In case you are wondering how does my filter method works it's basically a scope

You can read an indepth write up about it here:

https://medium.com/@mykeels/writing-clean-composable-eloquent-filters-edd242c82cc8

See my QueryFilters and Filterable trait bellow  just in case

```
<?php
namespace App\Filters;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QueryFilters
{
    protected $request;
    protected $builder;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function title($term)
    {
        $lowerCaseTerm = strtolower($term);
        return $this->builder->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$lowerCaseTerm%");
    }

    public function postCategory($term)
    {

        return $this->builder->whereHas('postcategory', function ($query) use ($term){
            $query->where('id', $term);
        });
    }

    public function sort($term)
    {
        $sortArray = explode(",", $term);

        for($i = 0; $i <= $sortArray.length; $i++)
        {
            $sortBy = substr_replace($sortArray[i], "", -1);

            $sortChar = substr($sortArray[i], -1);

            $sortOrder = $sortChar == '+' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';  

            $this->bulider->orderBy($sortBy, $sortOrder);
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        foreach ($this->filters() as $name => $value)
        {
            //if method doesn't exists continue out of the loop 
            if ( ! method_exists($this, $name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            //method exists so check if it has a value payload so call the method with arguments
            if (strlen($value)) 
            {
                $this->$name($value);
            } 
            //it doesn't have a payload so call the method without arguments
            else 
            {
                $this->$name();
            }
        }
        return $this->builder;
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        //returns associative array of request body key value pairs
        return $this->request->all();
    }

}
```

And Filterable Trait

```
<?php
namespace App\Filters;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait Filterable
{
    public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilters $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the Searchable trait to the model you're trying to perform the search on?

Comment: yes, I have added it

Comment: Gotcha, I took a look at the Searchable trait from the Scout package and I think I see the issue. See below. Should at least give you a new error, hopefully it'll do what you want

Answer (score 3):

The search() method is not made to be added to an existing query, here is the method that gets added to your model by the searchable trait

```
public static function search($query = '', $callback = null)
{
    return app(Builder::class, [
        'model' => new static,
        'query' => $query,
        'callback' => $callback,
        'softDelete'=> static::usesSoftDelete() && config('scout.soft_delete', false),
    ]);
}
```

The function is static, it doesn't take a query builder as a paramater, and returns a new builder no matter what. So you can't chain Search onto a query but you can START with the search and then apply your filters

So instead of this

```
$posts = Post::filter($filters)->search($request->input('query'))->paginate(0);
```

Try this

```
$posts = Post::search($request->input('query'))->filter($filters)->paginate(0);
```